# Hive SQL - How to collapse records that have continuous date ranges?

Tags: hive

How do I create logic to combine multiple records that have continuous date ranges into a single row

the following sample data

```
Member_key  start_date end_date
1            1/1/2017   1/31/2017
1            2/1/2017   2/28/2017
1            3/1/2017   3/31/2017
2            1/1/2017   1/31/2017
2            3/1/2017   3/31/2017
```

would end up returning the following result set

```
1            1/1/2017   3/31/2017
2            1/1/2017   1/31/2017
2            3/1/2017   3/31/2017
```

I found the following link to be very helpful and I am sure I am on the right track but am running into errors when trying to convert the code to hive sql

http://betteratoracle.com/posts/35-collapsing-continuous-ranges-into-single-rows

here's where I am getting stuck (2nd to last line below - with the order by in my max(grp) over .....

```
with data as(
select 
member_key, 
case 
         when datediff(start_date, lag(end_date) over (partition by member_key order by start_date asc)) <= 1 then
           null
         else
           row_number() over ()
         end grp,

start_date, 
end_date
from default.eligibility_span_test
order by member_key, start_date
)
select member_key, start_date, end_date
, max(grp) over (order by member_key, start_date) sequence
from data
```

here are the insert statements I am using to add data to a test table:

```
insert into default.eligibility_span_test values (1, '2017-01-01','2017-01-31');
insert into default.eligibility_span_test values (1, '2017-02-01', '2017-02-28');
insert into default.eligibility_span_test values (1, '2017-03-01', '2017-03-31');
insert into default.eligibility_span_test values (2, '2017-01-01', '2017-01-31');
insert into default.eligibility_span_test values (2, '2017-03-01', '2017-03-31');
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the below query -

```
with eligibility_span_test as
(
select 1 as Member_key, from_unixtime(unix_timestamp('2017-01-01', 'yyyy-MM-dd'), 'yyyy-MM-dd') as start_date, from_unixtime(unix_timestamp('2017-01-31', 'yyyy-MM-dd'), 'yyyy-MM-dd') end_date
union
select 1 as Member_key, from_unixtime(unix_timestamp('2017-02-01', 'yyyy-MM-dd'), 'yyyy-MM-dd') as start_date, from_unixtime(unix_timestamp('2017-02-28', 'yyyy-MM-dd'), 'yyyy-MM-dd') end_date
union
select 1 as Member_key, from_unixtime(unix_timestamp('2017-03-01', 'yyyy-MM-dd'), 'yyyy-MM-dd') as start_date, from_unixtime(unix_timestamp('2017-03-31', 'yyyy-MM-dd'), 'yyyy-MM-dd') end_date
union
select 2 as Member_key, from_unixtime(unix_timestamp('2017-01-01', 'yyyy-MM-dd'), 'yyyy-MM-dd') as start_date, from_unixtime(unix_timestamp('2017-01-31', 'yyyy-MM-dd'), 'yyyy-MM-dd') end_date
union
select 2 as Member_key, from_unixtime(unix_timestamp('2017-03-01', 'yyyy-MM-dd'), 'yyyy-MM-dd') as start_date, from_unixtime(unix_timestamp('2017-03-31', 'yyyy-MM-dd'), 'yyyy-MM-dd') end_date
),
res as (select member_key, month(start_date) - row_number() over (partition by member_key order by start_date) as groupBy, start_date, end_date from eligibility_span_test)
select member_key, min(start_date), min(end_date) from res group by groupBy, member_key;
```

Above query will fetch those memberId where we don't have consecutive start and end dates and one memberId if we have consecutive dates